# Ember js params not passing properly

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the routes defined in following way

```
this.route('league', {path: '/league'}, function () {
    this.route('matches', {path: '/'});
    this.route('create-team', {path: '/:matchId'}, function () {
        this.route('team',{path: '/team'});
    });
});
```

And i am trying to load all the players associated with a matchId inside `team` router as following

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.query('player', {'match': params.matchId});
    }

});
```

The problem is that the params is empty. I tried to pass in hard values to the json query and it worked with get request but it doesn't work like this. Where am i going wrong with this ?

Answer (score 2):

In your child route, you can call [paramsFor](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/Route/methods/paramsFor?anchor=paramsFor) and fetch the parameters (including query parameters) for a named route.

In your case, I believe you'll call

```
let params = this.paramsFor('league.create-team')
let match = params.matchId;
```